# Code that can read in letters in a .txt file

Tags: java, text-files, bufferedreader, filereader

I am writing a program thats supposed to read a simple text file and output a list of all the letters in that .txt file, ordered with the most frequently used letter to the least frequently used letter.

I have finished coding a working Java program that asks for file name and outputs the text within the file. But I am unsure how to go about outputting a list of the letters. What I am not sure specifically is what methods(if any) within the reader class I could use that reads in each letter in the .txt file. Any help would be appreciated!

This is current code:

```
// Here I import the Bufered Reader and file reader Libraries
// The Buffered Reader library is similar to Scanner Library and 
// is used here to read from a text file. File reader will allow
// the program to access windows file system, get the text file
// and allow the Buufered Reader to read it in.
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextFileReaderApp
{
    // I added "throws exception" in case there is an an error in the
    // main method, throw an exception, so it can prevent further
    // errors from occuring if java doesnt know the main methods going
    // to throw an error.
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        // below I diplay a welcome messgae to the user
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Text File Reader application!");
        System.out.println();

        // Below I create an instance of the Scanner class to get
        // input from the user.
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String selection = "y"; //this is the string variable that's used in
                                //the while loop to continue the program.

        // Below I created a while loop that continues the program if the user
        // keeps selecting y as their selecion
        while (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
            // this line of code is supposed to ask the user for text file name under
            // the C:/ directory and must not be hidden in any foler.
            System.out.print("Please enter the name of the .txt file: C/");
            FileReader file = new FileReader("C:/" + userInput.next());

            // file object is used as a parameter in buffered reader.
            BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(file);

            // below I create and initialize an object of type string called text that will
            // store whats inside of the text file.
            String text = "";

            // I use the readLine statement to read line after line of the text.
            // Once it has read everything it will return null.
            String lineText = textReader.readLine();

            // code below is a test for me to see if the code above works and is able to read
            // the text inside the file and output it.
            while(lineText != null)
            {
                // this reads the text line for line and ads it to the text variable for output.
                text = text + lineText + "\n";
                lineText = textReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(text);
        }
        // These 3 code lines ask the user if he/she would like to continue with the program.
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Continue using the Text File Reader? (y/n): ");
        choice = user_input.next();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: you're going to want to read the javadoc of the Reader class in java.

Comment: This is a series of statements asking us to write code for you, not an actual question.

Comment: No, I dont expect anyone to write code for me but I just simply want to know a method  within the reader class that can read the letters of the words in the text. I can handle everything beyond that but I just wanted to clarify.

Comment: You wan't to use `textReader.read()`, see my answer for an example :) hope it helps, just write if you need something else clarified.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to count letters / characters you can do it just as well on lines / words etc. No need to involve the Reader here.

```
 for (char c : someString.toCharArray ()) {
     // handle the character
  }
```

Should work once you have any String from your file.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you might want to use a StringBuilder instead of your String text because of alot better performance.
"text = text + lineText" will create another String object every time it is executed, StringBuilder works better in this case).

One way to achieve what you want is to read character for character of your textLine and use a switchcase block with all letters and add them to an array containing integers when they occur. Example:

```
int[] array = new int[26];
switch(character){
case "a": 
    array[0] += 1;
    break;
case "b": 
    array[1] += 1;
    break;
//....
}
```

and so on...
in the end you use a simple for loop and print the values of your array. Now you see how many times you have entered which character.

Comment: Thanks for your input! So from my understanding I would have to write code for each letter that increases the count of an array element by one? I could create an array with 26 elements and just increment a certain element by 1 every time it reads in a character. One question though, could I use something like an if/else if statements instead of a switchcase block? I'm not too familiar with using switchcase blocks, Im still fairly new to java.

Comment: Yes that would be my suggestion.
of course you can do it with if/else blocks as well but using switch/case looks alot cleaner and is easier to read.
You might want to have a look at this page:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 0):

This reads all characters from `textReader` until EOF is reached or an exception occurs.

`try {
    for(int i = textReader.read(); i != -1 /* EOF */; i = textReader.read()) {
       char c = (char) i;
       // do whatever you want with your char here
    }
} catch(IOException)
    textReader.close();`